# RGB color detection in Python Language

Tags: python

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 and Pi camera. I am doing an image processing program that could detect yellow colour and right now I am testing it but in frame nothing happen.My color detection is wrong?
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of yellow color in HSV
    lower_yellow = np.array([204,204,0])
    upper_yellow = np.array([255,255,254])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only yellow colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're filtering an HSV image with what looks to be RGB values. If you're looking for yellow, then you want to have a narrow hue range, and then saturation and value wider.

Yellow is roughly 60 degrees for hue, which means around a value of 30 for OpenCV (as the hue value is half the degree value to it can fit in the range 0-255). Similarly, your saturation and value shouldn't be the full range of 0-255 otherwise things that are close to black or white will match.

Try something like

```
lower_yellow = np.array([20, 30, 30])
upper_yellow = np.array([40, 200, 300])
```

This will hopefully get you close, but you still may have to play around with the numbers to get what you want.

Comment: That's really mostly trial and error and depends what you're trying to do. You can look at HSV sliders (like http://colorizer.org/) to point you in the right direction.